# In Readers-Writers Problem. Why can't a reader enter into critical section when writer is writing

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

I understood that writer should not enter into critical section when another writer is writing.
Because It causes a problem like result have to be 1 but 2. But I think there is no such a problem like this when reader enters into critical section while writer is writing or writer enters into critical section while reader is reading.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the scenario:

1. Reader enters CS.
2. Writer enters CS.
3. Writer modifies the value of a certain shared resource.
4. Reader reads that value and exits CS.
5. Writer again changes that value.
6. Writer exits the CS.
   So, this is the problem: The reader has read the incorrect value other than the value the writer had eventually set. This could lead to a whole lot of problems.